# Fastlane + ReactNative 0.40 does not compile

Tags: ios, react-native, fastlane

Since updating to React native 0.40 that now supported namespaces, my project will not compile.

So what was before:

```
#import "RCTEventEmitter.h"
```

is now:

```
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>
```

How can I define this for Fastlane to compile?

Error:

```
 'React/RCTEventEmitter.h' file not found

#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>
        ^
```

Comment: This did the tick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41488258/3238178