# React Native Xode Archive failed

Tags: xcode, reactjs, react-native

Xcode version is 8.2.1 
React Native version is 0.40

When I try to archive the app, I got the error like below.

```
'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found
```

Is anyone have this same problem before? How to fixed it?

Comment: Maybe this will help, [React Native / Xcode Upgrade and now RCTConvert.h not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477241/react-native-xcode-upgrade-and-now-rctconvert-h-not-found/)

Comment: I have the same problem! When I build my project there is no error but when I want to Archive it, Xcode gives me that error