# Can't add native packages to detached Expo project with Xcode (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, xcode8, detach, expo

I am trying to add native dependencies to a blank Expo project for react-native. I keep getting this error after the build in Xcode: `‘React/RCTBridge.h’ file not found`. The particular library I want to use is `react-native-camera`, but I have tried other libraries and they don't link correctly either.  I can get the libraries to link correctly with projects created with `react-native-init` and `create-react-native-app` (which has been detached).  Here are the steps I took to create and detach from the expo project:

**EDIT (I did steps 4,5, and 8 differently for different types of linking)**

1. I created a new exp project.
2. I added the following to my app.json:

   `"ios": {
       "bundleIdentifier": "com.yourcompany.yourappname",
       "supportsTablet": true
   },
   "android": {
       "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname"
   }`
3. `exp detach`
4. `npm i react-native-camera@0.6 --save`
5. `react-native link`
6. `npm i`
7. `cd ios`
8. `pod install`
9. `exp start`

I have attempted the following solutions (A, B, C):

A. From: [react-native-camera's docs](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera)
**1)Mostly automatic install with CocoaPods
2)Manual install**

B. From : [the expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v18.0.0/guides/expokit.html#changing-native-dependencies)

> because react-native link is not aware of CocoaPods, it may not do a
>   complete job installing your dependency. If you encounter build issues
>   locating the  headers, you may need to manually add
>   Pods/Headers/Public to the Header Search Paths configuration for your
>   native dependency in Xcode...The target you care to configure is the one created by react-native link inside your Xcode project. You’ll want to determine the relative path from your library to Pods/Headers/Public

By doing this:
[image]

C. And, finally, I tried
[This answer from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477241/react-native-xcode-upgrade-and-now-rctconvert-h-not-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(SRCROOT) refers to the native module's source folder rather than the top-level root of the whole project.

I had to use $(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/Pods/Headers/Public based on the location of the native module I ws bringing in (under node_modules).

Comment: This was a pretty easy fix once I used the correct relative path.  The problem is there is so much other information about how to fix this problem (the other steps I tried above) that really have nothing to do with the problem in Expo.  Thank @ Kelvin Lawson

Comment: Actually, I think I applied method C from my initial question to my project, and I think that might have been necessary, too.

Comment: The .xcodeproj file (in this case RCTCamera.xcodeproj) does not seem to be in source control, since it resides in `node_modules`. So setup on a new machine or even after a "npm install" can be cumbersome. Do you have a solution for this?