# RCTConvert.h file not found in React-Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, native-module

I would like to use FastImage module. 
(https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image)

But it's not working when I build it.

I did npm install & react-native link.

But when I build in iOS and Android, I've got an error.

iOS Error in RCTConvert+FFFastImage.h

> RCTConvert.h' file not found

Android Error.

> Error:Cannot choose between the following configurations of project :react-native-fast-image:
>     - debugApiElements
>     - debugRuntimeElements
>     - releaseApiElements
>     - releaseRuntimeElements
>   All of them match the consumer attributes:
>     - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
>         - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>         - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
>     - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
>         - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>         - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.
>     - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
>         - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>         - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but wasn't required.
>     - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
>         - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' but wasn't required.
>         - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>         - Found org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' but wasn't required.

First, I tried good answer in stackoverflow. 
([React Native / Xcode Upgrade and now RCTConvert.h not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477241/react-native-xcode-upgrade-and-now-rctconvert-h-not-found))

But it's not working for me.
And I create issue on the FastImage in github, But it's no answer so I can't close yet. (https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/117)

I need help..

My spec.

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^24.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-24.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-masonry": "^0.4.5",
    "react-native-scalable-image": "^0.2.2",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "^24.0.0"
  }
```

Xcode version. 9.2
Android studio. 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Add path/project folder/ios/Pods/Headers/Public in your Library's Build Settings -> Header Search Path as recursive. The issue will get resolved