# 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found on IPA export

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I would like to export an IPA of my application to test it on real conditions on a device.

With the simulator all is good, I can build it, test it and use my application.

I can also run the app on my devices (iPhone + AppleWatch).

But when I select in Xcode:

**Product** > **Destination** > **Generic iOS device + watchOS device**

**Product** > **Archive**

I have the following error... :

`[...]/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration/RCTVibration.h:10:9: 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found`

**Why the build process is different between the simulator and the IPA export ?**

Thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477241/react-native-xcode-upgrade-and-now-rctconvert-h-not-found