# How to fix "React/RCTConvert.h' file not found" error in archiving iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I going to publish my iOS app, but I having "lexical & preprocessor issue" during archiving.
[image]

I am implementing react-native-firebase in my project and after run the the "react-native link react-native-firebase", I have the error in archiving my app, but I have no problem in debug build and run app in simulator or real-device.

I have tried number of fixes, but not working:

- Unlink -> relink -> clean -> build -> archive
- remove -> re-install the node-module -> link -> Clean -> rebuild -> archive
- [React Native / Xcode Upgrade and now RCTConvert.h not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477241/react-native-xcode-upgrade-and-now-rctconvert-h-not-found)
- https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/releases/tag/v3.2.2

Dependencies & version:

- React-native 0.55.4
- XCODE 10 & Legacy build
- React-Native-Firebase 5.2.1

Does anyone experience same as mine, please give me some advise. Thanks!

Comment: try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477241/react-native-xcode-upgrade-and-now-rctconvert-h-not-found/41480099#41480099